# unable to locate the dump csv file from mysql

Tags: mysql

Consider this code:

```
mysql> select *  into outfile 'atmout12.csv' fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' from atm_atm;
ERROR 1086 (HY000): File 'atmout12.csv' already exists

mysql> select *  into outfile 'atmout1.csv' fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' from atm_atm;
Query OK, 2822 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

I used the above snippet to convert a table data to a CSV file. As you can see the query ran fine, but I am unable to locate where the file is.

I do an `ls` in the folder and can't locate it. I am using Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: `sudo find / -iname atmount12.csv`

Comment: sorry, that does not return anything.

Comment: that's because you are looking on the local server, but `select * into outfile` saves stuff on the remote server where MySQL lives.

Comment: i am running a server on local machine and doing everything locally, no connection as of now to any of remote servers.

Comment: Did you try specifying an absolute path? SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/dump.csv'... ?

Comment: No i didnot, the command as i wrote has been shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The file will be locate in your data directory.

example: datadir=/opt/data/db_name.

Inside the particular database (db_name) folder/dir will contain your .csv file.

OR else we can give the output file in particular location , to generate like that the user should have super privileges.

example :
mysql > use db_name
mysql> select *  into outfile 'atmout1.csv' from atm_atm;
or 
mysql> select * into outfile '/opt/example.csv' from atm_atm;

NOTE :above output file will be in db_name folder.